# Commenting and Un-Commenting a Node in an XML Document

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

```
<node1>
    <node2>
         <node3>
         </node3>
         <node3>
         </node3>
         <node3>
         </node3>
    </node2>

    <node2>
         <node3>
         </node3>
         <node3>
         </node3>
         <node3>
         </node3>
    </node2>

    ...
 </node1>
```

Let's say I have this structure in an XML document. I would like to be able to **comment  a node** and all its content and to **uncomment it if necessary**, using `PHP`. I tried to find a way looking at DOMDocument's documentation and SimpleXML's documentation without success.

Edit: Just to clarify: I found how to comment a node, but not how to uncomment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments can be created using [`DOMDocument::createComment()`](http://php.net/domdocument.createcomment).  Replacing comments with actual nodes is just like replacing any other node type, use [`DOMElement::replaceChild()`](http://php.net/domelement.replacechild).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <a>
        <aardvark/>
        <adder/>
        <alligator/>
    </a>
</example>
');

$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);

// Comment by making a comment node from target node's outer XML
$comment = $doc->createComment($doc->saveXML($node));
$node->parentNode->replaceChild($comment, $node);
echo $doc->saveXML();

// Uncomment by replacing the comment with a document fragment
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($comment->textContent);
$comment->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $comment);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

The (super-simplified) examples above should output something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <!--<a>
        <aardvark/>
        <adder/>
        <alligator/>
    </a>-->
</example>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <a>
        <aardvark/>
        <adder/>
        <alligator/>
    </a>
</example>
```

**Reference**

- [`DOMDocument::createComment()`](http://php.net/domdocument.createcomment) to create `<-- comments -->`
- [`DOMElement::replaceChild()`](http://php.net/domelement.replacechild) to swap nodes around
- [`DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment()`](http://php.net/domdocument.createdocumentfragment) to create a *document fragment*
- [`DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML()`](http://php.net/domdocumentfragment.appendxml) to append a string of xml to a fragment
- [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.savexml) to get the XML for an element
- [`DOMCharacterData->data`](http://php.net/domcharacterdata#domcharacterdata.props.data) to get the content of a comment

Comment: You are amazing. Thank  you for your time, I'll study those methods carefully.